# how to addClass as user is deleting text from input

Tags: jquery, input

I am running this code:

```
 $('body').on('keypress', '#other-text', function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
            $("#step5 button[type='submit']").removeClass("disabled");
        } else if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
            $("#step5 button[type='submit']").addClass("disabled");
        }
    });
```

the first if statement is working well, the function works as needed and the `removeClass` is applied.

On the other hand, the else is not working incase the user deletes the text, so I want to add the class again...

I tried:

```
$('body').on('keydown', '#other-text', function() {
        if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
            $("#step5 button[type='submit']").addClass("disabled");
        }
    });
```

as a response to the first function but it didnt work. Is there any way I could make it work incase the user delete the input value so that it adds the class?

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the value is not blank -

```
$('body').on('keydown', '#other-text', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $("#step5 button[type='submit']").addClass("disabled");
        }
    });
```